# I am having problems trying to get my hotspot to work

Tags: tethering

I have an at&t Lg V20 with Cricket: Unlimited Plan and CANT get my hotspot to work, I've tried to change my APN like I did with my G4 but it does not work and I've tried foxfi and a few others like it and still NOTHING.. Can you help me , Please?????

Comment: What doesn't work? There is no internet connection is being shared or the hotspot doesn't start? Can you be more accurate? And I don't remember a hotspot needs an APN...

Comment: @esQmo I think its carrier specific, carriers like Verizon block hotspot functionality where there is no data plan. Some workarounds involve changing apn type  to `dun` and I think that what OP is suggesting.

Comment: When trying to enable mobile hotspot what error are you getting? Your case is most likely to be carrier related. Have you considered contacting you carrier with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what your problem is but the only time I have a problem is when connecting a new device and forget I have to put the Mac address in the phone. Maybe that's your problem?